# Google Chrome Extension - Add Google custom search Engine as overlay

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add google custom search engine to my browser extension. Not sure how to add it to my chrome extention code

manifest.json

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Scoop",
    "description": "Info Locator",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "icon_128.png"},
    "content_scripts": [{
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": [
            "https://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.js", "content-script.js" ],
        "css": ["custom.css"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        // "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ]
  }
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SideNotes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #333;
        }
        #title {
            font-size: 42px;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" style="padding: 20px">
        <div id="toolbar">
          <h1 id="title">S C O O P</h1> 
          <img id="logo" src="image/icon.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="all-notes">
            <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div id="take-note">
            <form id="new-todo-form" method="POST" action="#">
                <div class="gcse-search"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul id="todo-items">
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                <li>lorem ipsum</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/db.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

content-scripts.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender){
    if(msg == "toggle"){
        toggle();
    }
})

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
iframe.style.background = "#e7f1f8";
iframe.style.height = "100%";
iframe.style.width = "0px";
iframe.style.position = "fixed";
iframe.style.top = "0px";
iframe.style.right = "0px";
iframe.style.zIndex = "9000000000000000000";
iframe.frameBorder = "none"; 
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html");

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

function toggle(){
    if(iframe.style.width == "0px"){
        iframe.style.width="400px";
    }
    else{
        iframe.style.width="0px";
    }
}
```

[image]
background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,"toggle");
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to add custom search engine via my chrome extension?

Comment: How to make an API call?